# Comparing two SQL queries in Crystal Reports and performing calculations on separate data points

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-xi

I'm not sure if this has been asked already but I'll take a shot and see what happens.

For my work we have been using Excel to generate all of our reports from instrument data. We recently implemented a Laboratory Information Management System that uses an SQL database and Crystal Reports to generate reports. I've had the fun (sarcasm) of recreating every report we run in Excel in Crystal Reports. There's one that I'm having the worst time to create. The report compares information for two samples. It compares information for one sample and then information from a replicate of that sample. I've tried every which way to bring in the data but it just repeats it for every record that's in the query. Here's a general idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have two queries that bring in the same data. One query lists the original sample that I need and the second query lists the replicate that I need to use data from to calculate as well as every other sample. Essentially they're the exact same query. You can see below in the link.

Here is the query. http://tinypic.com/r/wiu591/8

For the report, I need to pull the data for two separate samples and compare it using crystal reports and perform calculations. Below is a picture of the report, the RER field is a calculated formula. I've brought in this query twice and before anyone asks "did you make links"....yes, I have and it just repeats the data because these are essentially two different records in two separate queries that are the same. I'm at a loss for ways to configure this.

Here is the gist on what the report needs to look like. I'm open if anyone can see a better way to redesign it. http://tinypic.com/r/123ayh1/8

NOTE: In the columns that say Sample and Replicate these ones are C10575 and C10575R and the data for each is below.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Typically I put the two queries into one sql statement. One result set.  So a row would have both the original and replicated data in it.  You have to have to have a common key to join them on or resort to other SQL tricks.  You may have to use the same table twice in your query such as when you use MyTests t1  and  MyTests t2  .

Comment: Are you referring to the SQL query itself or having two commands of the same SQL query in Crystal Reports?

Comment: I am suggesting the original query from SQL have everything you need for both tests in one row.  So there is No Special work in the Crystal report.  Your query would bring back a record set similar to your final report, no special Crystal actions.

Comment: The only problem with that is each row would need to be the sample and replicate. Maybe add another table and do a case statement and say when the sample is not equal to the original query? Also, the primary key is sample code

Comment: So with crystal reports you generally either want to do all of the logic in a command, or all of the logic in the report.  Could you provide a clearer example of what you're trying to accomplish?  It sounds like using an SQL Expression field could help.

Comment: In the question above there are two images listed. The top one is an example of the query that I have to work with. The second link is the report itself. What I need to do is format the report to give me a sample and a replicated and the data associated with it, in this case C10575 and C10575R, and list the values and then perform a calculation on the values. Or format the report in such a way that it will list the samples side by side and perform calculations on the data. The second link is an image of the Excel report.

Comment: Those images are too blurry for me to read...

Comment: They show up perfectly fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to bring in two queries into the same view. I used the management studio to accomplish this. I brought in the two queries and didn't link them on the primary key which was the sample code. I linked on what these samples had in common. From there I did some fancy SQL'ing to sort out the samples I didn't need and presto. Got exactly what I need to throw into the crystal report and perform the calculations.